# Цикл for, c#, повторение

Tags: c#, for

`this.label1.Text = table.textBox1.Text;`

как сделать для этой строки цикл, что бы `label1` и `textbox1` увеличивались на 1, типо

`this.label2.Text = table.textBox2.Text;`

далее

`this.label3.Text = table.textBox3.Text;`
и тд

Comment: Нужна пояснительная бригада. Какой тип приложения? Что значат эти строчки кода, которве вы привели? В чём заключается суть проблемы?

Comment: this.label1.Text = table.textBox1.Text; эта строчка передаёт текст из 2 формы в 1 форму, нужно сделать цикл который будешь увеличивать значение label1 и textbox1 на 1

Comment: Winforms чтоли? Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях, отредактируйте сам вопрос, а комментарий удалите.

Comment: смею предположить что можно нужно сделать 2 массива в которые добавить label-ы и textBox-ы. А потом проходиться циклом по индексам от 0 до N (количества лейблов/текстбоксов)

Comment: Да, совершенно верно

Comment: Давать контролам имена только чтобы потом делать из них коллекзию для прохода циклом - так себе занятие. Если бы вы привели конкретный пример, зачем оно в принципе нужно, возможно я бы предложил что-то получше, и возможно попроще, чем банальный цикл. Но вопрос [окутан завесой тайн](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение в лоб, не вдаваясь в подробности.

```
const int count = 10; // допустим, у вас известное количество пар контролов
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    Label label = (Label)Controls.Find($"label{i}", true)[0];
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find($"textBox{i}", true)[0];
    label.Text = textBox.Text;
}
```